# Using cordova plugin in a polymer app

Tags: cordova, polymer, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an Android app using Polymer and Cordova. I need to use the NFC-phonegap plugin.

My problem is that i can't use the plugin from inside a webcomponent. The 
`nfc.variousUtilityFuncion()` item is available at the index.html level, but obviously doesn't pierce inside webcomponents.

Is there a way to use that item from inside a component?

Comment: I think you may be misidentifying the problem. The nfc object is likely added to the window global object & web components do not prevent accessing global objects. So guessing that your plugin isn't getting properly initialized.

Comment: As sfeast said. I'm using Polymer with Cordova with no problem. You can access the Cordova plugins anywhere.

Comment: how?.... i now it may sound "noobish" bur i never found myself in the need of global variables.... so i don't really know how to manage them.... is something like document.nfc, or window.nfc? @jptknta since you have experience in my use case.... could you be more specific? that would be of great help

Comment: It's javascript running a browser... it's an imperfect environment to say the least.  Some cordova plugins define a "namespace" of their own by putting and their "namespace" object in the global scope.  For example the StatusBar plugin does that. So, for example, you can call "StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(color)" anywhere.  Other's put an object on the navigator, e.g. the splash screen plugin does that, so you might use it by calling "navigator.splashscreen.hide()", for example.  They don't appear to be consistent. You have to read the docs for each.